# missing ; before statement in an xml response?

Tags: jquery, xml

I cant seem to figure out why I am getting that error "missing ; before statement" in this part of my xml response...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Time="2010-02-05T06:56:30" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/config.xsd">
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the parser says the error is in line 1, the root cause may be anywhere in the data. That is a very common mistake to think that the actual problem in your code is the line that the parser breaks on.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your entire response?  It needs to be a closed element if so:

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Time="2010-02-05T06:56:30" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/config.xsd" />
```

The change is the **`/>`** at the end.  This may not be the whole error though...if this doesn't resolve the issue, please post the jQuery code making the call.

Comment: yeah thats not the entire response

Comment: @magikman - Posting a small subset of the code doesn't help :)  Post the full response an code calling it.  It's like saying "help my car won't turn"...and only providing the mechanic with only the steering wheel

Answer (score 0):

Missing semi-colon in line 1 probably refers to your javascript, not your Xml. perhaps one of the javascript includes didn't end with a semicolon, and then line 1 of the following script resuits in an error.